# UIButton animation title position changed unexpected

Tags: animation, uibutton, swift4

UIButton animation title position changed suddenly (jumped to the left), I want to keep the title in the button center nearby always.

[image: image description]

You can see the button title ("Login In") jumped to the left unexpected, which should be optimized.

Here is the code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.loginButton.bounds.size.width -= 80.0
        }){ (yes) in }
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.loginButton.center.y -= 60.0
        self.loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.63, green: 0.84, blue: 0.35, alpha: 1.0)
        self.spinner.center = CGPoint(x: -20, y: -16)
        self.spinner.alpha = 0.0
  }){ (yes) in  }
```

Here is the code I tried , which does not work too.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.2, options: [], animations: {

       self.loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.63, green: 0.84, blue: 0.35, alpha: 1.0)
       self.loginButton.bounds.size.width -= 80.0
       self.loginButton.center.y -= 60.0
       self.spinner.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: -20, y: 16)
       self.spinner.alpha = 0.0
 }) { (isOK) in        }
```

---

PS:

I add the login button through storyboard , as the following image

[image: image description]

And the code relevant is [here](https://github.com/dengV/Anima_Ray/blob/master/BahamaAirLoginScreen/ViewController.swift)

Comment: How you add Login button? upload code for adding login button

Comment: Info Updated @JD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add line in animation function

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.2, options: [], animations: {

    //Your code for animation
    .    
    .
    .


    //Add this line
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}) { (isOK) in        }
```

**Note**

Use **Auto Layout** for all device support and easy to animation